# How do you shoot in the direction your character is facing using spriteRenderer flip?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to shoot bullets in the direction my character is facing. I instantiate my bullet prefabs.My player script is as follows:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator animator;
    Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    public Transform groundCheck;


    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if (Input.GetKey("d") || Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(2, rb2d.velocity.y);
            animator.Play("PlayerRun");
            spriteRenderer.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("left"))
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(-2, rb2d.velocity.y);
            animator.Play("PlayerRun");
            spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
        }

        else
        {
            animator.Play("PlayerIdle");
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb2d.velocity.y);
        }}
```

And my shooting script is as follow:

```
public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    PlayerController player;
    public Transform firePoint;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    SpriteRenderer sr;
    private bool direction;

    void Start()
    {
        player = GetComponent<PlayerController>();
        sr = player.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        direction = sr.flipX;

    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        if(direction)
        Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);

    }
}
```

My bullets at this point don't even appear to spawn, and if I delete all the extra code my bullets only spawn in the default direction that is right. My camera is a child of the player and if my character is facing left the bullets still go to the right. Is there a way to fix what I'm doing or do i take a different tangent?

Comment: I guess that you have code not shown here that moves the bullet in its local forward direction. Don't use sprite flipping in that case. Instead, rotate the character gameobject: `if (Input.GetKey("d") || Input.GetKey("right")) { rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(2, rb2d.velocity.y); animator.Play("PlayerRun"); transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward); } else if (Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("left")) { rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(-2, rb2d.velocity.y); animator.Play("PlayerRun"); transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.back); }`

Comment: I did try this however it seems that the character isn't changing direction but the camera is? I'm not sure what's happenning

Comment: I guess your camera is a child or other descendant of the player...the question didn't mention that either. Derek's answer below should work, just be sure to place and rotate the firePointL object correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this :

```
    void Shoot()
    {
        if(direction)
        Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);

    }
```

Means your bullets will only spawn in that one direction when `direction` is true.
If you want to use this method you will need to add an `else` to that statement. Your code may look more like this :

```
    void Shoot()
    {
        if(direction) {
            Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePointR.position, firePointR.rotation);
        } else {
            Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePointL.position, firePointL.rotation);
        }

    }
```

Note the L and R. You'd need two separate transforms to denote the left and right direction.

Comment: Ahh yes I understand your point. However, when I do add two gameObjects and position the transforms like your code suggest, it still only fires in one direction. I think i misunderstood the seperate transforms. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @mathgeek you need to rotate `firePointL` to have the rotation you want the projectile to have. Try putting `180` for the y axis of its rotation

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code or how it's written but here's another way of writing it, for those who want to reduce code repetition:

        
        `void Shoot() { Transform firePoint = direction ? firePointR : firePointL;
        Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation); }`

Comment: I did try doing what you mentioned but it still only shoots towards one direction. Is there a chance that direction=sr.flipX is not correct? I'm basically trying to access the bool value from the playercontroller but maybe it's not rightly done

Comment: Nope, nothing wrong with that. How does the bullet move? Is there a script on it that gives it a velocity, if so please append that to your question. It's likely the next culprit.